# How to handle UISplitViewController when there is no data?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there a best practice implementation for the case of a UISplitViewController with no data?  In case it's relevant, my app uses coredata and will ship with an example set or two, but, obviously, the user may decide to delete that data, in which case there will be zero data.

Specifically, is there a standard such as keeping the UIPopoverController open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A nice (design) perspective on this is:

- [Designing for the empty states](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/09/designing-for-the-empty-states/)

You could use this in your possibly empty views to give the user some subtle hints on how to add new data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll update my question with more specifics.